# FLV Playback AS3 Playlist Sequence

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, playlist

Help me please I need my AS3 FLVPlayback component sequentially play one play list xml and that this is repeated indefinitely, until the moment I got this code, which only lets you choose which video you want to play but do not go to the next automatically only stops...

I appreciate very much your prompt help, greetings from Ecuador

AS3 CODE:

```actionscript
var vlist:XML = new XML();
var XML_URL:String = "vids.xml";
var vlistURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(vlistURL);
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
function xmlLoaded(evtObj:Event) {
   vlist = XML(myLoader.data);
   for (var i=0; i<vlist.vid.length(); i++) {
      vid_select.addItem({label:vlist.vid[i].@desc, data:vlist.vid[i].@url});
   }
   vlist.ignoreWhitespace = true;
   vid.play(vid_select.getItemAt(0).data);
   vid_select.selectedIndex = 0;
}
var vidList:Object = new Object();

function changeHandler(event:Event):void {
   vid.play(vid_select.getItemAt(vid_select.selectedIndex).data);
}
vid_select.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var vlist:XML = new XML();
var XML_URL:String = "vids.xml";
var vlistURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(vlistURL);
var currentVideo:Int = 0;
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
function xmlLoaded(evtObj:Event) {
   vlist = XML(myLoader.data);
   for (var i=0; i<vlist.vid.length(); i++) {
      vid_select.addItem({label:vlist.vid[i].@desc, data:vlist.vid[i].@url});
   }
   vlist.ignoreWhitespace = true;
   playVideo()
}

var vidList:Object = new Object();

function videoFinished(e:VideoEvent):void{
     vid.removeEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE,videoFinished);
     currentVideo++
     playVideo()
}   

function playVideo(){
     vid.play(vid_select.getItemAt(currentVideo % vlist.vid.length()).data);
     vid_select.selectedIndex = currentVideo % vlist.vid.length();
     vid.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE,videoFinished);
}

function changeHandler(event:Event):void {
    currentVideo = vid_select.selectedIndex;
    playVideo();
}
vid_select.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);
```

Comment: You are adding a listener each time `playVideo()` is called. Fix that please.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, I appreciate your help ... I tried the suggested code change me, but I get the following error:

Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, line 14, column 36 1119: Access to undefined property COMPLETE possibly through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: add that line in your class import fl.video.VideoEvent

Comment: VideoEvent.COMPLETE is defined in flash 10.1 & below. if it doesnt work try using Event.COMPLETE instead

Comment: No works by putting import fl.video.VideoEvent, the same error keeps coming... I also tried with: vid.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, videoFinished); and I came out the following error:
TypeError: Error # 1034: Type Coercion failed: can not convert fl.video::VideoEvent@75edeb1 to flash.events.VideoEvent.
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction ()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent ()
at fl.video::FLVPlayback/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::handleVideoEvent ()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction ().....

Comment: try this Event.COMPLETE

Comment: I also tried with: vid.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, videoFinished); and I came out the following error: TypeError: Error # 1034: Type Coercion failed: can not convert fl.video::VideoEvent@75edeb1 to flash.events.VideoEvent. at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction () at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent () at fl.video::FLVPlayback/adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::handleVideoEvent () at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction ().....

Comment: change this videoFinished(e:VideoEvent) to videoFinished(e:Event) also

Comment: Now he did not leave any mistakes, but do not play the next video

Comment: does videoFinished works end of the video? and be sure of your second video url is fine

Comment: if the second video url okay ... I see that also can not choose the second video manually on my list.

Comment: I edit the following: function changeHandler (event: Event): void {
     vid.play (vid_select.getItemAt (vid_select.selectedIndex) .data);
}
vid_select.addEventListener (Event.CHANGE, changeHandler); ...
The Code makes me want to play select video manually, if I choose the last video from the list works VideoFinished

Comment: But still does not work playing the next video automatically. I can do?

Comment: instance FLV Playback clip vid is in timeline am i right?

Comment: i changed some lines in playVideo and videoFinished functions, you can try with Event instead of VideoEvent

Comment: Ye, FLV Playback instance: vid

Comment: Thank you so much Özgür Ersil, works with Event. : D

Comment: could you click approve so the others can see it's working? Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a listener to your `FLVPlayback` instance for [`VideoEvent.COMPLETE`](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#event:complete), which is dispatched once your video player has reached its selected video stream's end. There, you can select next video from your `vid_select` and launch a new playback of that.